# Calling bridged superclass static factory method from initializers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

There is a `UIView` subclass ([ALAlertBanner](https://github.com/lobianco/ALAlertBanner/blob/master/ALAlertBanner/ALAlertBanner.h) - written in Objective-C) in a 3rd party library which I'm using and I would like to subclass this class in Swift in order to customize it - lets call it `MyAlertBanner`.

In Objective-C instances of `ALAlertBanner` are created using static factory methods like these:

`+ (ALAlertBanner *)alertBannerForView:(UIView *)view style:(ALAlertBannerStyle)style position:(ALAlertBannerPosition)position title:(NSString *)title;`

...and these get bridged across to `init()` methods in Swift like these:

`alertBanner = ALAlertBanner(forView: alertBannerView(),
                style: ALAlertBannerStyleNotify,
                position: ALAlertBannerPositionUnderNavBar,
                title: title)`

I can use these methods in Swift without any problem.

In `MyAlertBanner` I go to implement an init method with the same method signature as the bridged-over factory method like this:

```init(forView: UIView, style: ALAlertBannerStyle, position: ALAlertBannerPosition, title: String, subtitle: String) {
        super.init(forView: forView, style: style, position: position, title: title, subtitle: subtitle) // compiler error here

```
}
```

```

However I get a compiler error:

`Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'ALAlertBanner'`

I can silence the compiler by calling `super.init(frame: CGRect)`, but that means my instance of `MyAlertBanner` is not properly initialised - I need to call the full static factory method with the required parameters.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Is there any way to placate the Swift compiler and say "hey - I know what I'm doing here!"?

Options I've been considering:

- subclass in Objective-C instead (not ideal as I'm trying to keep this greenfield project in Swift as much as possible for future maintenance reasons)
- create a static factory method in the Swift subclass, but this is not very idiomatic Swift.

Comment: Just a thought: XYZBanner will likely move to Swift sooner or later ; at which time you may have to maintain your code anyway ; thus your suggestion of bridging the initializer in Objective-C sounds pretty clever to me, and a reasonable solution.

Comment: Can you point to `XYZBanner` src and factory code?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect thanks for the comments. I've updated the question to make it an actual concrete example rather than an abstract question.